# Code efficiency

Tags: java, json, algorithm

I have to solve a problem where I've got a matrix filled with natural numbers reaching from 1 to n x m (rows x columns).
Depending on the corner of the `matrix`: `( (1,1), (1,m), (n,1), (n,m) )` and the `direction`: `(N,E,S,W)`.  I have to return an array with the numbers lying on the way from one corner to the other. The turn happens always when an end is reached. 
For example: 3x4 matrix, start at corner: `(1,1)`, Direction: `south`
result: `[1,2,3,4,8,7,6,5,9,10,11,12]`

I made this code but I think there is a way to make it more efficient.
Can anyone help me improve this code's efficiency?

Thanks!

```
public static JSONObject transformJSON(JSONObject input)
{
    JSONObject resultObject = input;
    int rows = resultObject.getInt("rows");
    int columns = resultObject.getInt("columns");
    int startRow = resultObject.getInt("startRow");
    int startColumn = resultObject.getInt("startColumn");
    String direction = resultObject.getString("direction");

    JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray();

    if(startRow == 1 && startColumn == 1)
    {
        if(direction.equals("EAST"))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                if(i%2 == 0)
                    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                        resultArray.put(i * columns + (j+1));   
                else
                    for(int j = columns * (i+1); j > columns * i; j--)
                        resultArray.put(j);
            }
        }
        else //SOUTH
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            {
                if(i%2 == 0)
                    for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                        resultArray.put(j * columns + (i+1));
                else
                    for(int j = 1 + columns * (rows - 1) + i; j >= i + 1; j = j - columns)
                        resultArray.put(j);

            }
        }
    }
    else if(startRow == rows && startColumn == 1)
    {
        boolean even = false;
        if(direction.equals("EAST"))
        {
            for(int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if(even == false)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                        resultArray.put(i * columns + (j+1));
                    even = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int j = columns * (i+1); j > columns * i; j--)
                        resultArray.put(j);
                    even = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else //NORTH
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            {
                if(even == false)
                {
                    for(int j = 1 + (rows - 1) * columns + i; j >= i + 1; j = j - columns)
                        resultArray.put(j);
                    even = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                        resultArray.put((i+1) + j * columns);
                    even = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else if(startRow == 1 && startColumn == columns)
    {
        if(direction.equals("WEST"))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                if(i%2 == 1)
                    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                        resultArray.put(i * columns + (j+1));   
                else
                    for(int j = columns * (i+1); j > columns * i; j--)
                        resultArray.put(j);
            }
        }
        else //SOUTH
        {
            for(int i = columns-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if(i%2 == 0)
                    for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                        resultArray.put((i+1) + j * columns);
                else
                    for(int j = 1 + (rows - 1) * columns + i; j >= i + 1; j = j - columns)
                        resultArray.put(j);

            }
        }
    }
    else if(startRow == rows && startColumn == columns)
    {
        boolean even = true;
        if(direction.equals("WEST"))
        {
            for(int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if(even == false)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                        resultArray.put(i * columns + (j+1));
                    even = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int j = columns * (i+1); j > columns * i; j--)
                        resultArray.put(j);
                    even = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else //NORTH
        {
            for(int i = columns-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if(even == true)
                {
                    for(int j = 1 + (rows - 1) * columns + i; j >= i + 1; j = j - columns)
                        resultArray.put(j);
                    even = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                        resultArray.put((i+1) + j * columns);
                    even = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }


    JSONObject transformedJSON = new JSONObject();
    transformedJSON.put("solution", resultArray);
    return transformedJSON;
}
```

And my test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    JSONObject test1 = new JSONObject();
    test1.put("rows", 3);
    test1.put("columns", 4);
    test1.put("startRow", 1);
    test1.put("startColumn", 1);
    test1.put("direction", "EAST");

    JSONObject test2 = new JSONObject();
    test2.put("rows", 3);
    test2.put("columns", 6);
    test2.put("startRow", 1);
    test2.put("startColumn", 1);
    test2.put("direction", "SOUTH");

    JSONObject test3 = new JSONObject();
    test3.put("rows", 5);
    test3.put("columns", 4);
    test3.put("startRow", 5);
    test3.put("startColumn", 1);
    test3.put("direction", "EAST");

    JSONObject test4 = new JSONObject();
    test4.put("rows", 5);
    test4.put("columns", 4);
    test4.put("startRow", 5);
    test4.put("startColumn", 1);
    test4.put("direction", "NORTH");

    JSONObject test5 = new JSONObject();
    test5.put("rows", 4);
    test5.put("columns", 5);
    test5.put("startRow", 1);
    test5.put("startColumn", 5);
    test5.put("direction", "WEST");

    JSONObject test6 = new JSONObject();
    test6.put("rows", 4);
    test6.put("columns", 5);
    test6.put("startRow", 1);
    test6.put("startColumn", 5);
    test6.put("direction", "SOUTH");

    JSONObject test7 = new JSONObject();
    test7.put("rows", 4);
    test7.put("columns", 5);
    test7.put("startRow", 4);
    test7.put("startColumn", 5);
    test7.put("direction", "WEST");

    JSONObject test8 = new JSONObject();
    test8.put("rows", 4);
    test8.put("columns", 5);
    test8.put("startRow", 4);
    test8.put("startColumn", 5);
    test8.put("direction", "NORTH");

    System.out.println(transformJSON(test1).toString());
    System.out.println(transformJSON(test2).toString());
    //System.out.println(transformJSON(test3).toString());
    //System.out.println(transformJSON(test4).toString());
    //System.out.println(transformJSON(test5).toString());
    //System.out.println(transformJSON(test6).toString());
    //System.out.println(transformJSON(test7).toString());
    System.out.println(transformJSON(test8).toString());

}
```

Comment: i think i know a way, but i didn't entirely understand the demand, could you add the virtual matrix you are 'walking' on? from the example you provided, it seems like there is a matrix with fixed numbers (1 to 12 from right to left and from top to bot) and there is a kind of character who walks on the matrix from the top-lefts corner, on this order [E,E,E,E,S,W,W,W,S,E,E,E], so i don't see how SOUTH is the direction here. (assuming 1,1 is NORTH-EAST)